# Nested UIScrollView's for paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement a paging solution using nested `UIScrollView`'s and have an annoying problem which am finding troublesome to resolve.

The view loads up just fine but as soon as the user initiates a scroll the view pops off the top by about 20 pixels and will bounce back to that position when pulled down.

I have followed the guidelines in other answered questions but can't seem to nail what the problem is.

When I use the innerScroll on its own, vertical works just fine.
Soon as I nest it, the problem occurs.

I've tried to increase the `contentSize` height to be more than the height of the content as I guessed that would be the issue but doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
CGRect screenSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);

_theScrollView=[[customScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:screenSize];
_theScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
_theScrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
_theScrollView.bounces = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                                           target:self
                                                                           action:@selector(performAction:)];
NSArray* buttons = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:barButton, nil];

CGSize scrollViewContentSize = screenSize.size;
scrollViewContentSize.width = screenSize.size.width * self.thisform.formPages.count;
scrollViewContentSize.height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
_theScrollView.contentSize = scrollViewContentSize;

self.actionButton = barButton;
self.picVisible = NO;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;

UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(onCancelButtonSelected:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

self.views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_thisform.formPages.count];

int i = 0;
NSSortDescriptor *byPage = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"formPageNumber" 
                                                       ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortedPages = [self.thisform.formPages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: byPage, nil]];

float zoomScale=1.0;

UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    zoomScale=1.0;
} else {
    zoomScale=1.3;
}

BOOL isNew;

for (FormPages *page in sortedPages) {
    NSData *formImage = page.formPage;

    //innerScroll
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:formImage];
    Imager *imageView = [[Imager alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    imageView.tag = page.formPageNumber;
    imageView.fieldCollection = [Utility populateFormFields:self.thisform 
                                                 pagenumber:page.formPageNumber];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(_theScrollView.bounds.size.width * i, 0, _theScrollView.bounds.size.width, _theScrollView.bounds.size.height);

    float contentWidth = _theScrollView.bounds.size.width;
    float contentHeight = imageView.frame.size.height;

    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake (contentWidth,contentHeight);

    TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *innerScroll = [[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    innerScroll.contentSize = contentSize;
    [innerScroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    innerScroll.minimumZoomScale=1;
    innerScroll.zoomScale = zoomScale;
    innerScroll.maximumZoomScale=2.5;
    innerScroll.delegate = self;
    innerScroll.scrollsToTop=NO;
    innerScroll.currentView = imageView;

    imageView.frame = screenSize;

    CGSize pageSize = [Utility GetPageSize:self.thisform];

    float viewWidth = imageView.frame.size.width;
    float formWidth = pageSize.width;
    float viewHeight = imageView.frame.size.height;
    float formHeight = pageSize.height;

    float widthRatio = viewWidth / formWidth;
    float heightRatio = viewHeight / formHeight;

    [self populateControls:NO
                      view:imageView
                widthRatio:widthRatio
               heightRatio:heightRatio];

    [innerScroll addSubview:imageView];
    [_theScrollView addSubview:innerScroll];
    [self.views addObject:innerScroll];

    i++;
}

[self.view addSubview:_theScrollView];
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you running this on?
Also, have you checked the bounds of your view (and it's superviews)? Even If a single view in the superview hierarchy has incorrect bounds, it might screw with the contained views.

Comment: Sorry, should have said its IOS7 and I'm pretty sure it was working okay prior to that. I'll check as suggested. Thanks

Comment: So here's the bounds of each view

Comment: So here's the bounds of each view

self.view frame (0 0; 768 1024)
_theScrollView frame (0 0; 768 1024) contentSize = (width=768, height=1024)
innerScroll frame (0 0; 768 1024) contentSize (width=768, height=1650)
imageView frame (0 0; 768 1024)

Comment: Try adding borders to each view, with different colours. Quickest way to know which view is actually moving. Also, `self.view.bounds` might *not always* return screen dimensions (specially in `viewDidLoad`). Use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` instead. Once you set the borders, you'll see if the frame is being resized, or just translated.

Comment: Add `layer.borderColor` to `self.view` also, to check it's participation.

Comment: Thats helped me to understand the issue. Its answered in this article below. Feeling a bit embarrassed I didn't spot it myself but I really appreciate you getting me on the right track. Thanks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824994/view-got-hidden-below-uinavigationbar-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

In IOS7 translucent property of the UINavigationBar is set to YES by default rather than NO as in  previous IOS versions as answered in previous question.

[View got hidden below UINavigationBar iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824994/view-got-hidden-below-uinavigationbar-ios-7)