# Navigation Bar covers some part of view at Top

Tags: ios, swift

When I instantiate a view Controller through `didSelectRowAtIndex` method:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("About") as About
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
break;
```

A part of the `About` View Controller gets below the navigation Bar. How Do I solve this in Swift?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [View got hidden below UINavigationBar iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824994/view-got-hidden-below-uinavigationbar-ios-7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the edges for the extended layout to none.

**Swift 2**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
```

**Swift 3+**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

**Swift 4+**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
```