# The last Row of TableView in a ContainerView is Hidden Behind TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbar

Building an app that has tabbar. One of the tab, I need to use container view because I'm switching between three table view. That switching works well, so I will not show you those code to be clear. However, those tables are hidden behind tabbar. Like:
[image]

I'm using storyboard and the container view is such that:
[image]

So here I put intentionally container to the top of tabbar, because I don't want overlapping. Then with using these codes, I thought that would help me to find the bound of container and set it to the tableView:

[image]

The code line `vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;` is what I'm telling. But that doesn't work at all, clearly, since table is still behind the tabbar.

There are solutions I found on internet, such as setting consentInsent of tableView in `viewDidLoad`, unchecking some properties of tabbar and making tabbar opaque. None of those worked. The reason I'm asking it this basically. I had to because I can't find a solution worked for my case.

Hope you can see the problem and help me to figure it out.

Please ask me if you need more information / explanation.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just making sure. You can't scroll the table content so that last row will be fully visible above tabbar? Or are you actually expecting for whole table content to be drawn atop the tabbar (which would hide it basically)?

Comment: are you take table view using storyboard, if yes then set the constraint on it.

Comment: The first line of adding inital viewController refers to it @PravinTate .So with calling 'viewControllerForSegmentIndex' I'm taking table via their identifiers.

Comment: so why you are not set constraint to table using storyboard ?

Comment: Because I thought setting the container's constraint will be enough and when I take its bound as explained above, table will shrink to those bounds. Am I wrong here @PravinTate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

where tab bar is not show set constraint as follows
[image]

Please try to set constraint like this, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for you! However, here is the problem. I have container which I switch into with 3 tableView. So under container there s a tabbar. But under tableViews there are no tabbars, so I can't set the constraints like that tho.

Comment: How it possible if u set bottom Marin 49 then it must be run perfect

Comment: Hold on. Figured it out! Well the problem was my table was slightly bigger then the bottom margin, I hadn't recognize it and working on different solution. God it was just in front of me, that is annoying. Anyway, for reminding me and indicating me that I got a problem with the tableView, you got the accepted answer. Many thanks to you !

Answer (score 4):

Try unchecking the **under bottom bar property** of the view controller from storyboard. If it doesn't work also uncheck the **Adjust ScrollView Inset** property over there.

Also you must be sure that bottom Layout constraint must be set to Bottom Layout Guide instead of superview.

Comment: Yeah what I meant with 'unchecking some properties' was exaclty those actually. Didn't work for me :(

Comment: Have you confirmed the bottom layout constraint is set to Bottom Layout Guide instead of superview ? Also there is no need to set frames through code as it will not work.

Comment: There is vertical space constraint between 'Container View.Bottom' and 'Bottom Layout Guide.Top'

Comment: Then the workaround for this could be remove this vertical constraint to Bottom Layout Guide and set it to superview with the constant value equal to the height of tab bar.

Comment: Also the bounds will not give you the correct value as per applying auto layout constraints in ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: If I can't take the bound of container, how will setting vertical constaint will help me?  Or do you suggest me to that to the tables, not container?

Comment: I mean that in ViewDidLoad you don't get updated values. Try forcing the constraints to be updated before picking the bounds.

Comment: What exactly you meant, sorry I couldn't catch how to do it.

Comment: I think, the bounding works properly. I figured out the problem as you can see in the accepted answer comment. However, I'm so greatful to you for your greatly efforts!

Comment: Ok Ignore it. For better understanding I am making it clear here, first of all check what does the bounds value you are getting in ViewDidLoad method. I am sure it will not be as expected, the reason behind this wrong value will be the time at which you are accessing content view bounds, its bounds has not been updated as per the constraints you set. So you need to force the updation of constraints here or have to move this code to be executed later times.

Comment: The second suggestion is, if you are adding the tableViews as subview to your container view the constraints you would have set on tableview relative to its superview would have been removed. So instead of adding tableview you should add tableview's superview as subview of container view.

Comment: Aha, I like what you talk about especially in the second advise. Really, it is useful. With both, you really made me clear, I'm greatful to you. Thanks lot

Comment: My Pleasure :). Please accept those comments to be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but without a table view and with Swift. Anyway my view got hidden behind my tab bar.

```
if let tabBarController = tabBarController {
    tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Using this in my UIViewController which is shown by the UITabBarController solved the issue for me. I had the same problem with the navigation bar which is why I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824994/view-got-hidden-below-uinavigationbar-ios-7) but it also worked for the tab bar.